# Tabcontroller throwing error when scrolling up in listview

Tags: flutter, dart

My scrollcontroller for my listview controller is linked with my tab bar, through a function I created below. When I scroll up however, the console throws this error:

'Failed assertion: line 155 pos 12: 'value >= 0 && (value < length || length == 0)': is not true.'

I can't seem to solve the error, should I disable the scrollcontroller when the user reaches offset == 0? How can I do this if so?

```
  void _scrollListener() {
    var index = (_scrollController.offset / 70).round();
    if (index > choices.length)
      index = choices.length;
      setState(() {
        _tabController.animateTo(index, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeIn);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think that the tab indexing by default starts from 0.
Let's say we have 3 tabs and 3 choices. The correct way to load any one of the tabs will be to pass an index between 0 and 2. 
If we use your code for this example this will cause an exception because

```
index = choices.length;
```

index will have a value of 3 and _tabController doesn't have an item on that position.